# Error al llamar método Asíncrono desde servicio WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Hola cree un Web Service con la plantilla que te da por defecto VS y al incluir el WS en una aplicación me crea los métodos asíncronos por defecto pero al momento de quererlos llamar me manda error.

Este es el metodo en el WS

```
[OperationContract]
 string GetData(int value);
    
     
    
public string GetData(int value){
    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
```

Y para llamarlo utilizo

```
ServiceReference2.Service1Client c = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
var t = await c.GetDataAsync(1);
```

Y me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que estoy haciendo mal?

Edit:
Hola Ramiro a mi no me sale esa opción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tenes la opcion cuando lo llamas y te crea todo que no sea asincrono?

Comment: Corrijo mi comentario, cuando llamas al servicio te da una serie de opciones, si no estoy equivocado tenes la opcion que no te cree los metodos asincronicos.

Comment: Sip, si no le picó a esa opción me crea el asíncrono y si le picó a que me los cree me crea 2 el normal y el asincrono

Comment: Pero el asíncrono no funciona me manda error

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una respuesta que quizas te sirva, pero proba borrar el servicio y llamarlo de nuevo y fijate en las opciones avanzadas que tengas declaradas estas opciones.

En el metodo llamo de las dos maneras al servicio y obtengo el resultado esperado en los dos.

```
private async void Datos()
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    var s = service.GetData();
    var t = await service.GetDataAsync();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera me funciona correctamente.